# Websocket connection not working in Django Channels ('WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/board/7/' failed:')

Tags: python-3.x, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to get a websocket running for a Django project I'm working on, but I can't get the websocket to connect, which is strange since I copied the example chat application from. the channels documentation and that worked fine but when I copy-pasted that same code over to my project, it didn't.

So, here are the relevant sections of code:

the relevant view in views.py

```py
def board_view(request, key):

    board = get_object_or_404(request.user.boards, pk=key)

    key = dumps(board.pk)
    return render(request, 'core/board.html', 
            {"board":board, "permission":user_permission, "key":key})
```

board.html (the relevant part)

```html
    <script>
        const key = JSON.parse("{{key|escapejs}}");

        const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            'ws://'
            + window.location.host
            + '/ws/board/'
            + key
            + '/'
        );
```

routing.py

```py
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"^ws/board/(?P<key>\d+)/$", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

consumers.py

```py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer


class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type':'connection_established',
            'message':'you are now connected'
        }))

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json["message"]

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message}))
```

asgi.py

```py
import os
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sketchboard.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

import core.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(core.routing.websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
})
```

settings.py (relevant part):
`ASGI_APPLICATION = 'sketchboard.asgi.application'`
and

```
INSTALLED_MY_APPS = [
    'core',
]

INSTALLED_EXTENSIONS = [
    'daphne',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'guest_user',
    'guest_user.contrib.allauth',
    'rest_framework',
    'channels',
]
```

This is almost identical to the tutorial websocket setup found in the [channels documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/index.html) (which worked fine when I tried it).

So what I should be getting from the console on the 'board_view' page is 'you are now connected' (as defined in `consumers.py`), however instead I am getting a

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/board/7/' failed:`
message.

I should point out here that the 7 is the 'key', which is a dynamic variable, but this part definitely works.
I've also tried just typing in 'test' as the route in `board.html` and `routing.py`
so something like:

`const chatSocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/test');`
But I get the same error, so I don't think the problem lies in the `routing.py` or `board.html` files.
I've also tried asking the [django discord server](https://discord.com/invite/xcRH6mN4fa) but they were unable to help.

This problem really has me stumped so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you installed channels version 4 which is the latest, default one, and this does not start the ASGI server in development mode. please verify this and install channels version == 3.0.5 . do verify ASGI server starts when you run the runserver command.

( Version 4 supports ASGI server via daphne, I guess so, not tried.)

If not let me know will discuss more.

[image]

Comment: I am using channels version 4, but it does run on a development server, as the command prompt verifies (similar to the image you posted). Also, the error I get from the console on the webpage does say there's a websocket, it just fails to connect to it. I also just tried using channels version 3.0.5 and Django doesn't seem to recognize it anymore. But channels 4 does definitely run in the development server as well.

Comment: you also need to install Redis database, have you installed redis and check whether it is working or not . using redis cli.

Comment: I get a similar message when my Redis doesn't work, and have you also installed channels_redis?

Comment: does your command promt verifies starting ASGI/channels  development server

Comment: I haven't installed redis because I haven't implemented channel layers yet, so there shouldn't be any need for it yet. That'd be the next step, but thought it best to actually get the connection working the thing working in the first place first. And I know that should work because as I mentioned before, I copy-pasted most of the code straight from the tutorial project in the channels documentation (which is why this has me so mystified because it works in the example version, of course, I've tested that).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, even if I stop my Redis server and comment out the channel layer, I'm able to establish a connection. Let me recheck the question.

Comment: Have you been able to discern any more insight into what the problem may be?

Comment: Do verify your websocket_urlpatterns, I belive WebSocket expects a room name in the URL and not the key value,  re_path(r"ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),

Comment: Where does the websocket specify it's expecting a room name?

Comment: could you please clarify?

Comment: Can you please share your command promt' output when you start the dev server, and the error in detail.

Comment: Just wanted you to try replacing the **key** with **room_name** ,  and check if this works, you will find room_name in the example of the documentation,

Comment: Yes, I have tried using room_name instead of key, I've also tried just using 'test'. The name is completely arbitrary however and should have no effect on the websockets, as long as the routing.py and the view agree on the path.

Comment: Hi guys,
Any update about this issue ? Struggling with same issue for couple of weeks :/

Comment: I'm having the same problem (or similar) but I'm pretty sure that it was working for me in the past. It also works for me currently using daphne but not with the development server. With the development server, I get a 404. Maybe some combination of Python package updates that I installed broke it at some point?

Answer (score 5):

- For `channels==4.0.0` there was a change mentioned [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/4.0.0.html#decoupling-of-the-daphne-application-server) which requires that you also put `daphne` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, before `django.contrib.staticfiles`. Run also `pip install -U 'channels[daphne]' channels-redis` to be sure you have compatible `daphne` and `channels-redis` versions.
- Alternatively, seems that running `daphne <your main app>.asgi:application` from within your root of your project (where `manage.py` is) instead of the `python manage.py runserver` works.
- Additionally, as mentioned before, downgrading to `channels==3.0.5` is another way to make it work without adding `daphne` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Adding 'daphne' to INSTALLED_APPS did the trick.

Comment: it worked with me , you are the best.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this in settings.py file

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'appname.asgi.application'
```